# Async request with AutoComplete from API Using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

React code only works with certain API requests. For example, I'm able to pull data from `https://country.register.gov.uk/records.json?page-size=5000`, when I try to pull data from `http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey={api_key}&s=` I get a type error, Below is the working code, but databases have different formats in JSON files. I've tried different ways to solve but haven't been able to decipher the solution. Hoping someone can shine some light.

```js
function sleep(delay = 0) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, delay);
  });
}

export default function Asynchronous() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);
  const loading = open && options.length === 0;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let active = true;

    if (!loading) {
      return undefined;
    }

    (async () => {
      const response = await fetch('https://country.register.gov.uk/records.json?page-size=5000');
      await sleep(1e3); // For demo purposes.
      const res = await response.json();

      if (active) {
        setOptions(Object.keys(res).map(key => res[key].item[0]));
      }
    })();

    return () => {
      active = false;
    };
  }, [loading]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!open) {
      setOptions([]);
    }
  }, [open]);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="asynchronous-demo"
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      open={open}
      onOpen={() => {
        setOpen(true);
      }}
      onClose={() => {
        setOpen(false);
      }}
      getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.name === value.name}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
      options={options}
      loading={loading}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Asynchronous"
          fullWidth
          variant="outlined"
          InputProps={{
            ...params.InputProps,
            endAdornment: (
              <React.Fragment>
                {loading ? <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} /> : null}
                {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
              </React.Fragment>
            ),
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Working JSON

```json
[
  {
    "PT": {
      "index-entry-number": "147",
      "entry-number": "147",
      "entry-timestamp": "2016-04-05T13:23:05Z",
      "key": "PT",
      "item": [
        {
          "country": "PT",
          "official-name": "The Portuguese Republic",
          "name": "Portugal",
          "citizen-names": "Portuguese"
        }
      ]
    }
   
]
```

Getting Type error here

```js
function sleep(delay = 0) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, delay);
    });
}

export default function Asynchronous() {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);
    const loading = open && options.length === 0;

    React.useEffect(() => {
        let active = true;

        if (!loading) {
            return undefined;
        }

        (async () => {
            const response = await fetch('http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey={api_key}=');
            
            await sleep(1e3);
            const res = await response.json();
            console.log(res);
            if (active) {
             
             setOptions(Object.keys(res).map(key => res[key].Search[0]));
              
            }
        })();
        return () => {
            active = false;
        };
    }, [loading]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (!open) {
            setOptions([]);
        }
    }, [open]);

    return (
        <Autocomplete
            id="tags-outlined"
            style={{ width: 300 }}
            open={open}
            onOpen={() => {
                setOpen(true);
            }}
            onClose={() => {
                setOpen(false);
            }}
            getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.Title === value.Title}
            getOptionLabel={option => option.Title}
            options={options}
            loading={loading}
            renderInput={params => (
                <TextField
                    {...params}
                    label="Asynchronous"
                    fullWidth
                    variant="outlined"
                    InputProps={{
                        ...params.InputProps,
                        endAdornment: (
                            <React.Fragment>
                                {loading ? <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} /> : null}
                                {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                            </React.Fragment>
                        ),
                    }}
                />
            )}
        />
    );
}
```

Not working JSON

```json
{
  "Title": "Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2",
  "Year": "2017",
  "Rated": "PG-13",
  "Released": "05 May 2017",
  "Runtime": "136 min",
  "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Comedy, Sci-Fi",
  "Director": "James Gunn",
  "Writer": "James Gunn, Dan Abnett (based on the Marvel comics by), Andy Lanning (based on the Marvel comics by), Steve Englehart (Star-Lord created by), Steve Gan (Star-Lord created by), Jim Starlin (Gamora and Drax created by), Stan Lee (Groot created by), Larry Lieber (Groot created by), Jack Kirby (Groot created by), Bill Mantlo (Rocket Raccoon created by), Keith Giffen (Rocket Raccoon created by), Steve Gerber (Howard the Duck created by), Val Mayerik (Howard the Duck created by)",
  "Actors": "Chris Pratt, Zoe Saldana, Dave Bautista, Vin Diesel",
  "Plot": "The Guardians struggle to keep together as a team while dealing with their personal family issues, notably Star-Lord's encounter with his father the ambitious celestial being Ego.",
  "Language": "English",
  "Country": "USA",
  "Awards": "Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 12 wins & 42 nominations.",
  "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNjM0NTc0NzItM2FlYS00YzEwLWE0YmUtNTA2ZWIzODc2OTgxXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTgwNzIyNzg@._V1_SX300.jpg",
  "Ratings": [
    {
      "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
      "Value": "7.6/10"
    },
    {
      "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
      "Value": "84%"
    },
    {
      "Source": "Metacritic",
      "Value": "67/100"
    }
  ],
  "Metascore": "67",
  "imdbRating": "7.6",
  "imdbVotes": "513,275",
  "imdbID": "tt3896198",
  "Type": "movie",
  "DVD": "22 Aug 2017",
  "BoxOffice": "$389,804,217",
  "Production": "Walt Disney Pictures",
  "Website": "N/A",
  "Response": "True"
}
```

Error

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Type Error

```
 35 | console.log(res);
  36 | if (active) {
  37 |     // setOptions(Object.keys(movies).map(key => key.results[{}]));
> 38 |     setOptions(Object.keys(res).map(key => res[key].Search[0]));
     | ^  39 |     // setOptions(options.movies.map(results => results));
  40 |     console.log(Object.keys)
  41 | }
```

Comment: Please include the full error message that you are seeing when you run this code and possibly some sample JSON from the response that's throwing the error.

Comment: Just included Error and Json Files @DHerls